# Use the input from Haskeline's getInputLine

Tags: haskell, monads, haskeline

I have the code

```
 main :: IO()
 main = runInputT defaultSettings loop          
 where                                        
   --loop :: InputT IO ()                     
   loop = do                                  
     minput <- getInputLine "$ "              
     case minput of                           
       Nothing -> return ()                   
       Just input -> process $ words input          
     loop
```

Where process has the type definition

```
process :: [String] -> IO ()
```

However I get the error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘InputT m’                                                       
Expected type: InputT m ()                                                                     
  Actual type: IO ()                                                                           
• In the expression: process $ words input                                                       
In a case alternative: Just input -> process $ words input                                     
In a stmt of a 'do' block:                                                                     
  case minput of {                                                                             
    Nothing -> return ()                                                                       
    Just input -> process $ words input }
```

I was wondering if anybody could explain what I'm doing wrong.
I just want to raw input from getInputLine to do other things with.

Thanks

Comment: Try `liftIO (process $ words input)`.

Comment: That seems to do the trick. 
Thanks!

Would you mind explaining exactly what this is doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All statements in a `do` block must have the same type (well, must have the same monad in their type). In your case, this is `InputT IO something` (with the monad being `InputT IO`).

`getInputLine "$ "` has type `InputT IO (Maybe String)`, so that part is OK.

Then you have a `case` expression, which means all branches need to have the same type. The first branch is just `return ()`, which gets the type `InputT IO ()`. All good so far.

The second branch is `process $ words input`. But this has type `IO ()`, not `InputT IO ()`, which is what the compiler expects at this point.

To fix this: Fortunately there's an easy way to convert ("lift") a value of type `IO x` to `InputT IO x`, which is the `liftIO` function:

```
Just input -> liftIO (process $ words input)
```

That is, `liftIO :: IO a -> InputT IO a` (actually it's more general than that: `liftIO :: (MonadIO m) => IO a -> m a` but that doesn't matter here).

Comment: Great. Thanks a bunch!